# Automatically Update Data in a Google Fusion Table hourly?

Tags: ssis, google-fusion-tables

We are going to need to `update` data in a `Google Fusion Table` hourly and are looking into possibly using an `SSIS` package to accomplish this.

Has anyone had any experience with updating [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/drive/start/apps.html#fusiontables) automatically?  Any methods work better than others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would decompose your problem into smaller problems until you reach the point you have found one you can solve.

### How do I perform a task at X interval

In a pure Windows world, I'd use the native [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's free and works fine for your scenario of "every hour."

Since SSIS is in the mix, that means you would also have access to [SQL Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx). It too is a good fit for your scenario and at this point, I would examine your organization and determine what scheduling tool is predominantly used. It might be "neither."

### How can I programmatically update Google Fusion Tables

There is a full [Fusion API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) published. They even have a [DML syntax](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference) for working with data in a table. However, do observe the [warning](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#insertRow) about using the query syntax for more than 500 rows/10k cells/1MB.

> Note: You can list up to 500 INSERT statements, separated by
>   semicolons, in one request as long as the total size of the data does
>   not exceed 1 MB and the total number of table cells being added does
>   not exceed 10,000 cells. If you are inserting a large number of rows,
>   use the [import](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables) method instead, which will be faster and more reliable
>   than using many SQL INSERT statements.

### How can I use SSIS to update Google Fusion Tables

For anything that's not Out Of the Box with SSIS, I usually re-ask the question as "how do I do X in .NET" because that's what it will boil down to. Since it's a web destination, while SSIS has a web service task, it's not as useful as writing your own .NET caller.

I would envision an SSIS package with at least a `Data Flow Task.` Depending on where your data is coming from, it'd have a source (OLE DB, flat file, etc), any transformations you need between that and the destination. Your destination will be a `Script Component` configured as a Destination. There you'll use C# or VB.NET to send your Insert/Update commands to the web server. I found this [sample of C#](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/jJ9w7zgU8oQ) that sounds logical. I've never actually used GFT API so I can't comment on whether there's a better route of doing this.

## Copying sanya's comment in here

> Warning: the attached sample c# script uses Client Login to
>   authenticate against Google. This auth method has been deprecated
>   since April 20, 2012. Usage of OAuth2 is supported.

Comment: Warning: the attached sample c# script uses Client Login to authenticate against Google. This auth method has been deprecated since April 20, 2012. Usage of OAuth2 is supported.

Comment: ClientLogin suport has now been deleted - so the sample now breaks